# Loading facebook wall feed JSON issues

Tags: javascript, facebook, json, jquery

I'm trying to load a facebook wall feed with jQuery on the client side of my website. 
The feed I'm using for the facebook request is:

> http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=40796308305

I've tried the following aproaches:

1.

```
$.getJSON('http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=40796308305',function(data){
   console.log(data)

});
```

Which returns the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=40796308305. Origin http://xxxx.local is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

2.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        id: '40796308305',
        format: 'json'
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Returns the same error.

3.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        id: '40796308305',
        format: 'jsonp'
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
    }

});
```

Returns:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

And seems to be parsing the feed.

How do I load the facebook json feed so that I can access it as i do an array?

Comment: Once you have the JSON, you can already access it as an array.

Comment: My problem here is that I'm getting errors while using the approaches above to retrieve the JSON.

Comment: Have you tried putting the entire URL into method 3? That is, without the extra properties?

Comment: 2 and 3 are **exactly** the same (except white-space), not sure this is intentional...

Comment: My bad, copied the same one twice. One of the should've been using the jsonp dataType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with client-side only due to cross-domain policy restrictions.

You likely will need to create own proxy for that data (this endpoint for page data doesn't support JSONP and will not work with `callback` parameter)

Comment: In that case I'll do the JSON request in php and load that page with AJAX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change datatype from `json` to `jsonp`, since its a cross-domain call

Comment: That gave me the same result as #3. Which is:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Answer (score 0):

I see this thread is almost 6 months old so hopefully it's not too late.

```
function fbInfo(user, id) {
    var jurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+user+"&callback=?";
    console.log(jurl);
    $.getJSON(jurl, function(data) {
           //do stuff
});
}
```

I call the function in my html page and pass the username ("user") of the facebook page into the url variable "jurl"

Use the $.getJSON method, then manipulate the data at will.

This definitely works because I'm currently using it to pull business info from a facebook page into my website.