# angular-seed web-script.js and cors

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, cors

I'm stacked for second day... I'm trying to fetch some json from outside domain, but I broke with CORS. I'm almost sure [how to use JSONP in AngularJS resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025711/how-to-use-jsonp-in-angularjs-resource), that problem is with my node.js server which doesn't send

```
Origin: http://api.bob.com
```

So, I read zillion of CORS google answers, but all said the almost the same:

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
};

(...)

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

But... There's no anything similiar to app in scripts\web-script.js which I can use as app.

The web-script.js below (it is just from package)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var util = require('util'),
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    url = require('url'),
    events = require('events');

var DEFAULT_PORT = 8000;

function main(argv) {
  new HttpServer({
    'GET': createServlet(StaticServlet),
    'HEAD': createServlet(StaticServlet)
  }).start(Number(argv[2]) || DEFAULT_PORT);
}

function escapeHtml(value) {
  return value.toString().
    replace('<', '&lt;').
    replace('>', '&gt;').
    replace('"', '&quot;');
}

function createServlet(Class) {
  var servlet = new Class();
  return servlet.handleRequest.bind(servlet);
}

/**
 * An Http server implementation that uses a map of methods to decide
 * action routing.
 *
 * @param {Object} Map of method => Handler function
 */
function HttpServer(handlers) {
  this.handlers = handlers;
  this.server = http.createServer(this.handleRequest_.bind(this));
}

HttpServer.prototype.start = function(port) {
  this.port = port;
  this.server.listen(port);
  util.puts('Http Server running at http://localhost:' + port + '/');
};

HttpServer.prototype.parseUrl_ = function(urlString) {
  var parsed = url.parse(urlString);
  parsed.pathname = url.resolve('/', parsed.pathname);
  return url.parse(url.format(parsed), true);
};

HttpServer.prototype.handleRequest_ = function(req, res) {
  var logEntry = req.method + ' ' + req.url;
  if (req.headers['user-agent']) {
    logEntry += ' ' + req.headers['user-agent'];
  }
  util.puts(logEntry);
  req.url = this.parseUrl_(req.url);
  var handler = this.handlers[req.method];
  if (!handler) {
    res.writeHead(501);
    res.end();
  } else {
    handler.call(this, req, res);
  }
};

/**
 * Handles static content.
 */
function StaticServlet() {}

StaticServlet.MimeMap = {
  'txt': 'text/plain',
  'html': 'text/html',
  'css': 'text/css',
  'xml': 'application/xml',
  'json': 'application/json',
  'js': 'application/javascript',
  'jpg': 'image/jpeg',
  'jpeg': 'image/jpeg',
  'gif': 'image/gif',
  'png': 'image/png',
  'svg': 'image/svg+xml'
};

StaticServlet.prototype.handleRequest = function(req, res) {
  var self = this;
  var path = ('./' + req.url.pathname).replace('//','/').replace(/%(..)/g, function(match, hex){
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16));
  });
  var parts = path.split('/');
  if (parts[parts.length-1].charAt(0) === '.')
    return self.sendForbidden_(req, res, path);
  fs.stat(path, function(err, stat) {
    if (err)
      return self.sendMissing_(req, res, path);
    if (stat.isDirectory())
      return self.sendDirectory_(req, res, path);
    return self.sendFile_(req, res, path);
  });
}

StaticServlet.prototype.sendError_ = function(req, res, error) {
  res.writeHead(500, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
  });
  res.write('<!doctype html>\n');
  res.write('<title>Internal Server Error</title>\n');
  res.write('<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>');
  res.write('<pre>' + escapeHtml(util.inspect(error)) + '</pre>');
  util.puts('500 Internal Server Error');
  util.puts(util.inspect(error));
};

StaticServlet.prototype.sendMissing_ = function(req, res, path) {
  path = path.substring(1);
  res.writeHead(404, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
  });
  res.write('<!doctype html>\n');
  res.write('<title>404 Not Found</title>\n');
  res.write('<h1>Not Found</h1>');
  res.write(
    '<p>The requested URL ' +
    escapeHtml(path) +
    ' was not found on this server.</p>'
  );
  res.end();
  util.puts('404 Not Found: ' + path);
};

StaticServlet.prototype.sendForbidden_ = function(req, res, path) {
  path = path.substring(1);
  res.writeHead(403, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
  });
  res.write('<!doctype html>\n');
  res.write('<title>403 Forbidden</title>\n');
  res.write('<h1>Forbidden</h1>');
  res.write(
    '<p>You do not have permission to access ' +
    escapeHtml(path) + ' on this server.</p>'
  );
  res.end();
  util.puts('403 Forbidden: ' + path);
};

StaticServlet.prototype.sendRedirect_ = function(req, res, redirectUrl) {
  res.writeHead(301, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      'Location': redirectUrl
  });
  res.write('<!doctype html>\n');
  res.write('<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>\n');
  res.write('<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>');
  res.write(
    '<p>The document has moved <a href="' +
    redirectUrl +
    '">here</a>.</p>'
  );
  res.end();
  util.puts('301 Moved Permanently: ' + redirectUrl);
};

StaticServlet.prototype.sendFile_ = function(req, res, path) {
  var self = this;
  var file = fs.createReadStream(path);
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': StaticServlet.
      MimeMap[path.split('.').pop()] || 'text/plain'
  });
  if (req.method === 'HEAD') {
    res.end();
  } else {
    file.on('data', res.write.bind(res));
    file.on('close', function() {
      res.end();
    });
    file.on('error', function(error) {
      self.sendError_(req, res, error);
    });
  }
};

StaticServlet.prototype.sendDirectory_ = function(req, res, path) {
  var self = this;
  if (path.match(/[^\/]$/)) {
    req.url.pathname += '/';
    var redirectUrl = url.format(url.parse(url.format(req.url)));
    return self.sendRedirect_(req, res, redirectUrl);
  }
  fs.readdir(path, function(err, files) {
    if (err)
      return self.sendError_(req, res, error);

    if (!files.length)
      return self.writeDirectoryIndex_(req, res, path, []);

    var remaining = files.length;
    files.forEach(function(fileName, index) {
      fs.stat(path + '/' + fileName, function(err, stat) {
        if (err)
          return self.sendError_(req, res, err);
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
          files[index] = fileName + '/';
        }
        if (!(--remaining))
          return self.writeDirectoryIndex_(req, res, path, files);
      });
    });
  });
};

StaticServlet.prototype.writeDirectoryIndex_ = function(req, res, path, files) {
  path = path.substring(1);
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
  });
  if (req.method === 'HEAD') {
    res.end();
    return;
  }
  res.write('<!doctype html>\n');
  res.write('<title>' + escapeHtml(path) + '</title>\n');
  res.write('<style>\n');
  res.write('  ol { list-style-type: none; font-size: 1.2em; }\n');
  res.write('</style>\n');
  res.write('<h1>Directory: ' + escapeHtml(path) + '</h1>');
  res.write('<ol>');
  files.forEach(function(fileName) {
    if (fileName.charAt(0) !== '.') {
      res.write('<li><a href="' +
        escapeHtml(fileName) + '">' +
        escapeHtml(fileName) + '</a></li>');
    }
  });
  res.write('</ol>');
  res.end();
};

// Must be last,
main(process.argv);
```

Please, help me StackOverflow, you are my last hope.

Comment: really not clear what you are trying to do. Get data from another domain? Won't `$http` or ($resource) get it using angular?

Comment: Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025711/how-to-use-jsonp-in-angularjs-resource - there is my angular code. Of course insted of file.json i use http://example.com/file.json

Comment: that post is very confusing....does remote domain serve jsonp or not?

Comment: i'm not sure here's an example: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=459908330791 - but when i change method into GET => No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: right off the bat that feed url isn't valid anymore...look at the response. Surely they have an API you can acces for what you want that serves jsonp or is CORS enabled

Comment: Why isn't valid? I don't want to show the exact id - i pick random one - but the json format is exact the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have something like:
https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/scripts/web-server.js

So you have to add ALLOW CORS (look below I added 2 lines) to response headers:

```
StaticServlet.prototype.sendFile_ = function(req, res, path) {
  var self = this;
  var file = fs.createReadStream(path);
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': StaticServlet.
      MimeMap[path.split('.').pop()] || 'text/plain',
    // ALLOW CORS - line 1 !!!
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    // ALLOW CORS - line 2 !!!
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With'
  });
  if (req.method === 'HEAD') {
    res.end();
  } else {
    file.on('data', res.write.bind(res));
    file.on('close', function() {
      res.end();
    });
    file.on('error', function(error) {
      self.sendError_(req, res, error);
    });
  }
};
```

Maybe you have other function with jsonp, so add to `res.writeHead(200,` CORS headers too.